# OpenGL ES 2D - z-ordering, depth buffer vs drawing in order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm completely new to OpenGL so sorry if it's a silly question. Also no idea if it makes a difference, just in case, I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1.

Currently I'm drawing sprites in order of texture, as I've read it's better for performance (makes sense). But now I'm wondering whether that was the right approach because I need certain sprites to be in front of others regardless of texture.

As far as I'm aware, my options for z-ordering would be either to enable the depth buffer and use that, or to switch the drawing order so the sprites are drawn in the order of a z value.

I've read that the depth buffer can be a performance hit, but so would changing the order. Which should I do?

Comment: Since every reasonable OpenGL application uses the depth-buffer (except maybe a simple "draw a single 2D-texture"-example), I guess you should really relativate this "performance hit" statement down a bit (if even true).

Comment: One option is to side-step the whole issue and use a framework like Cocos2D. It'll take the OpenGL burden off you. It supports z-ordering of sprites, and can re-use textures with sprites by using CCSpriteBatchNode. (There's no way of interleaving batching texture binds & z-order changes, though.)

Comment: I'm doing the game more for the learning than anything else, so I decided start from scratch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is, sort the sprites.

It sounds like you're creating something that's really 2d based, and while a z-buffer can be a very useful tool, it can be an impressive performance hit if the hardware doesn't support it, and if you're not actually using 3d objects that may be intersecting one another, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

In addition, if you have any sprites that are partially transparent, i.e. have pixels with an alpha value that isn't 0 or 255 (or 0.0 or 1.0 if using floating point) then you have to sort anyway.

As a side note, I believe that the performance lost when changing "sprites" only occurs when switching out surfaces, and only rarely.  One way to help mitigate this problem is to put as many different sprites in one image as you can, on a grid, and use little pieces of your surfaces as sprites.

Comment: Since OpenGL is mainly intended for 3D (even ES), I guess a hardware that doesn't support a hardware depth-buffer, well, doesn't support hardware accelerated OpenGL ES, does it?

Comment: I don't think any iOS devices don't support it (I could be wrong I guess). You've brought up a good point though, because it's a tile-based game, all the tiles will be in a single image tilemap - because of this, the rendering in order issue shouldn't affect it?

Comment: Exactly right, the speed issue referred to when switching surfaces only applies when you change which image you're working from in memory.  It's actually only an issue when you exhaust video memory as well.  The real issue is when opengl runs out of space and has to unload images from video memory, then load new images.

Comment: I'm not particularly convinced by this argument. I've had "massive performance hits" from texture swapping before. It would be nice to actually do some investigation into this. If hardware z-buffer support could be detected, it might be a case of implementing both solutions and switching to whichever is most appropriate.